# magento after migration 404 without index.php and theme setting blank

Tags: magento-1.9, migration, htaccess, 404

After migrating magento, site is full of 404 errors.
Found that, if i can manually put index.php before every url - hurrey no errors

Able to login to admin with same index.php trick, and now i want to disable index.php so that all urls on site should work.

Going to system>configuration>Web>SEO>Use Web Server Rewrites = `yes` already.
and it dosent work.

In Addition Theme setting page is also blank.
tried modifying .htaceess with `RewriteBase` `/magento` to `/` but no luck.

[P.S. `404` are default server styled error and not custom magento error]
I suspect there must be some problem with web server settings, but i'm not sure
I want to fix these error, and looking for some reference or help 
Thank You.

Answer (score 0):

Check if you have an uncommented directive in your .htaccess like

```
DirectoryIndex index.php
```

Also the vhost should have

```
AllowOverride All
```

[This](http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/1_-_installation_and_configuration/installing_magento_ubuntu_9.04_server) is kinda old, but the vhost setup seems to be correct.

Comment: yes it is there `DirectoryIndex index.php` shud i remove it ?
Vhost is correct and have Rewrite enabled `AllowOverride All` present

Comment: No, its the right directive. You might be having issues with the hosting provider configuration since you have to pull some settings ad directives from your .htaccess in order to make the Magento run as expected. This is why you set AllowOvrride All in the vhost config. If its a shared hosting or something like that you will have to ask your provider for assistance.

Comment: Please check the DirectoryIndex does not have a # in front of it. Also check if the mod_rewrite is enabled with a2enmod rewrite and restarting apache later.

Comment: its a dedicated unmanaged centos , i'm the only responsible for every tweak and i do have access 
DirectoryIndex does not hace # but a line above it do have `#default index file` 
cant use a2enmod its centos 
Thanks

Comment: Then how do you know mod_rewrite is installed and enabled?

Comment: manually checked in httpd.conf for mod_rewrite.so without #

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/16064/discussion-between-echoashu-and-mbalparda).